# Twig for loop put every 1 element in a new container

Tags: symfony, drupal, twig

How to render like this with its own unique class name on every loop

```
{% for row in rows %}
    {{ row.content }}
{% endfor %}


<div class="item1"> Item 1 </div>
<div class="item2"> Item 2 </div>
<div class="item3"> Item 3 </div>
<div class="item4"> Item 4 </div>
```

and so on how do can i achieve this, Please help thanks.

or is there an other way where i can call each element in the for loop individually ???

Answer (score 2):

You can use `loop.index`:

```
{% for row in rows %}

   <div class="item{{ loop.index }}">{{ row.content }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... is there a way i can pull the content individually using and index number something like {{ row.content[0] }}  or     {{ row.content.0 }}